# Moving Admob banner ad to bottom of tableView embedded in a Navigation Controller (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am having trouble moving my banner ad to the bottom of my tableView which is embedded in a navigation Controller. When I launch the app nothing appears, and the delegate method tells me that the ad did correctly load. So the problem as it seems to me is that the value `UIScreen.main.bounds.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` is too large for my screen when I set the`bannerView.frame`. Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //Ad display
    let naviLen  = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeFullBanner)
    print(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                              y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - naviLen,
                              width: bannerView.frame.width,
                              height: bannerView.frame.height)
    bannerView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.adUnitID = Passwords.adMobAdID
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID]                    // All simulators
    bannerView.load(request)
```

And also my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FozrG.png)

Many thanks.

Comment: trying this way `UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 44`

Comment: That did not work. I updated the question with more detail.

Comment: post your code not image

Comment: I cannot embed images due to not having enough rep. but i will post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved my own problem; I figured I should post it for other people to see. I offsetted my y coordinate by the height of the navigation bar, the status bar and the banner height:

```
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeFullBanner)
    let offset  = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)! + bannerView.frame.height
    print(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                              y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - offset ,
                              width: bannerView.frame.width,
                              height: bannerView.frame.height)
```

Thanks for all the help.